# Install php via yum including mysql support

Tags: php, mysql, yum

Is it enough to specify php module like this to have mysql support?

```
yum install php
```

or should I use

```
yum install php php-mysql
```

Is there a difference?

Thanx.

Comment: this command: sudo yum install php php-mysql

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough. You will need to do:

```
yum install php php-mysql
```

To Install PHP and PHP-MySQL.